# Proving subvector spaces on R

Tags: elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

I am being asked the following:

Consider the following two subsets $V$, $W$ of $\mathbb R^n$:

(a) $V = \left\{ (v_1,\ldots,v_n) \in \mathbb R \mid \sum_{i-0}^n v_i = 0 \right\}$

(b)  $W := \{(v_1, \ldots , v_n) \in \mathbb R^n\mid v_1 = \cdots = v_n \}$

Show that $V$ and $W$ are subvector spaces of $R^n$, and determine for $V$ , $W$, $V \cap W$, and $V + W$ a basis and the dimension.

To prove that $V$ and $W$ are subvector spaces of $R^n$ I have said that because $0$ is in $\mathbb R^n$ I can multiply each set by $0$ and that is a linear combination showing that $0$ is in each set. I am unsure of how to prove that each set is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Also, the way I am thinking about $V$ is that it either consists of all $0$'s or every element in $V$ also has it's opposite somewhere in the set. That being said, I believe the dimension of $V$ would have to be 2 because it would take two vectors of the same magnitude in different directions to represent that relation. Using similar logic, I think the dimension of $W$ would be 1 because since all elements are equal, it would only take 1 vector to represent the set. However, I don't know how to transform that thought into a basis.

Answer (score 1):

For $V$ the elements of $V$ are n-tuple such that their sum is zero.Take any 2 n-tuple and add them then their sum is also zero since each of the n-tuple is zero and the element is $v_1+u_1,......,v_n+u_n$ So it is closed under addition .Under multiplication with a scalar is the same  since a $λ\cdot v=λ\cdot 0$ so it is closed under multiplication.And you have also the zero element.So  it is a subspace .Same logic for $W$ think the elements as n-tuples (if you add n-tuple that its component is equal with another n-tuple that its components are equal What can you say about the components of element $v_1+w_1......,v_n+w_n$   since $v_1=v_2....$ and $w_1=w_2...$

Comment: But how do you know that each element in $V$ is 0? Also, for the part you have in parentheses, if I say $p$ is one n-tuple and $q$ is another n-tuple with equal elements, are you saying that I can just say $p + q$ = $p + p$ = 2$p$?

Comment: Every element on V is  a n-tuple such that if you Add the components you get zero thats by the definition of the your set V.On the second part if you take an n-tuple $v_1,v_2....,v_n$ such that $v_1=v_2......=v_n$ and another n-tuple such that $w_1=w_2....=w_n$ and add those n-tuples  youll get $v_1+w_1,v_2+w_2,.....,v_n+w_n$ and since you know $v_1=v2$ and $w_1=w_2$ then you know $v_1+w_1=v_2+w_2$ You need to understand the sets you are given and what their elements are.